# Regular expression to match colon

Tags: c#, regex, powershell

I need to add an interface to an class in c# and need to match if has already been declared:

```
public partial class Client
```

Needs to be

```
public partial class Client: IEntity
```

When the occurrence already exists

```
public partial class Client: IEntity
```

Must remain

I have reached this "public partial class (\w+)" into "public partial class $1: IEntity"

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do here.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to handle that specific type of format (i.e. "public partial class 'classname'"). Something like this would do it:

```
class Program
{
    static readonly Regex re = new Regex( @"^public partial class[^:]+$", RegexOptions.Compiled );
    static string Replacement( string stringToReplace )
    {
        return re.Replace( stringToReplace, match => match.Value + ": IEntity" );                
    }   
    static void Main()
    {
        string newString = Replacement( "public partial class Client" );
        Console.WriteLine( newString ); //output: "public partial class Client: IEntity"
        newString = Replacement( "public partial class Server" );
        Console.WriteLine( newString ); //output: "public partial class Server: IEntity"
        newString = Replacement( "public partial class Server: IEntity" );
        Console.WriteLine( newString ); //output: "public partial class Server: IEntity"
    }       
}
```

Where:

- ^ means match from the beginning.
- $ means match to the end.
- [^:]+ means any character not ':'

Answer (score 0):

I'd say a straight up regex is a dangerous approach.

What if you have:

```
public partial class Client: RichClient
```

better be sure not to add an extra : IEntity

If it is possible you could maybe get the complete line text and then write a function to determine what to do.

Could there be a problem with spanning multiple lines?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for something like this

```
(get-content test.cs -raw) -replace 'public partial class (\w+)(:.*)?$','public partial class $1: IEntity'
```